# /myPage.xhtml @26,75 value="#{var.attribute}": Property 'attribute' not found on type com.sources.Class

Tags: java, jsf, javabeans

I'm having some issues I can't solve. I'm doing a h:dataTable, there are some attributes I can access and others I don't. Don't know why... Here is the code :

myPage.xhtml :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">

<h:head></h:head>

<h:body>
    <ui:composition template="/WEB-INF/templates/basic.xhtml">
        <ui:define name="content">
            <h:dataTable value="#{data.result}" var="table" width="30%" border="1">
                <h:column>
                    <h:graphicImage value="#{table.image}" width="200" height="200" />
                </h:column>
                <h:column>
                    #{table.name}
                </h:column>
                <h:column>
                    #{table.description}
                </h:column>
            </h:dataTable>
        </ui:define>
    </ui:composition>
</h:body>
</html>
```

Here is the Data.java :

```
package com.sources;

import java.util.List;

public class Data {
    private List<Article> result;

    public Data() {
        // name, description, image
        result.add(new Article("Tales of", "game", "/Images/" + "image.jpg"));
        result.add(new Article("Harry potter", "book1", "/Images/" + "image.jpg"));
        result.add(new Article("Harry potter", "book2", "/Images/" + "image.jpg"));
    }

    public List<Article> getResult() {
        return result;
    }
}
```

The `"/Images/" + "image.jpg"` path is correct, if I write `"/Images/image.jpg"` int the `h:graphicImage` `value`, it displays properly.

And to finish, the Article.java:

```
package com.sources;

import java.util.List;

public class Article {
    private String name;
    private String description;
    private String image;

    public Article() {}

    public Article(String name, String description, String image) {
        this.setName(name);
        this.setDescription(description);
        this.setImage(image);
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(final String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(final String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(String image) {
        this.image = image;
    }
}
```

In myPage.xhtml, I can access `#{table.name}`, `#{table.description}`, but not `#{table.image}`.

Here is the error I get : `/myPage.xhtml @26,75 value="#{table.image}": Property 'image' not found on type com.sources.Article`

Comment: This typically means that there isn't a `get` method in the class. However your class has the method. Try to clean and redeploy your project.

Comment: What do you mean clean ? Recreate the class ?

Comment: No. I don't know how you bild your project (in IDE or full build outside IDE). But you should make sure to clean the build, then compile and deploy your application again.

Comment: I'm using Eclipse Kepler and to launch the application, I just right-click on the .xhtml file > Run As > Run on Server. How do you want me to "clean the build" ?

Comment: I tried `Project > Clean...`, also cleaned the server, doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: Try removing the project from the application server.  Then clean and restart the server, and then add the project back in.  Your code looks correct to me, too.

Comment: So, I deleted the project and the server, recreate the server and the project (I copied the sources) AND the error is still here ! It's driving me crazy !!

Comment: Try to display the property's content simply as a `String` (inside `<h:column>`'s tags only).

Comment: It finally works. I have removed some code and classes till I have a functional project. Then I copied the code I removed, recreate the classes I deleted and copied on it the code there were in, and it works. Thanks Eclipse...